# Convert taken picture to bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, overlay, android-camera

I want to edit the photo that was just taken by the camera in my app. Got everything working in terms of taking a picture and saving that picture to the gallery; however, I want to get that picture before saving it so I can overlay an logo on it. My idea was running this bit of code in activity result:

```
/* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
```

then creating another bitmap with my logo and overlay that on the first bitmap. However the picture and drawable source are too big to decode into a bitmap and I get an `OutOfMemoryError`. I don't want to scale down my images, because it must be a high res image. What's the way to go now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Android:LargeHeap="true" option in the Manifest file. And allow image loading action only when you have enough available memory. (this param is available I think only since Android 3.0)

There is no magic. If image exceeds available memory, then you could read and edit parts of image. But it's not the most convenient way to process images.